# Where are the 12 trinkets hidden in Prelude of the Chambered?

Tags: prelude-of-the-chambered

I've been playing Notch's new ludum dare game -- [Prelude of the Chambered](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/index.html) -- and it's been kicking my butt.

At any rate, I've noticed that there are these golden trinkets scattered around (they look a little like a chalice), and when you die, you get a "X/12 Trinkets Collected statistic.

How can I find all twelve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first trinket is right at the beginning. After you break the first wall, go down the short passage to the right and break the wall there.
- The second is right after you get the power gloves in the dungeon. Right next to the ladder up to the prison there's a boulder blocking one. You'll want to stand on the right side and hit it as head on as possible without blocking it.
- The third is right after that, before you get the first key. Right across from the room with the four boulders in a cracked wall that you need to break.
- The fourth is right after you get in the frost cave. Simply go right at the beginning and slide across to it.
- The fifth is in the room with the skates. on the third pillar go left first or just wait until you get the skates and glide over there.
- The sixth is immediately to your right after you get the cutters - just cut through the bars.
- The seventh is back in the prison after you get the cutters, go to the long hall with all the bars and cut the farthest from the holes with the boulders in them.
- The eighth is to the right when you enter the crypt, guarded by a zombie.
- The ninth is also in the crpyt directly opposite the flippers.
- The tenth is next to the bars where the zombies where on the island. Swim across the small channel there and go around the bush.
- The eleventh is in the temple, behind a cracked wall where you pushed the boulder into the hole.
- The twelfth is in the temple, behind a cracked wall where you pushed the boulder into the hole - opposite to number eleven.